# Is CruiseControl.NET a Security Risk for Open Source Projects?

Tags: security, cruisecontrol.net

I am learning about CruiseControl.NET to implement continuous integration into my open source project. It looks like CruiseControl.NET will have to run on my personal computer, and it will build and execute new revisions automatically and immediately! It does not look like it would take a rocket scientist to hack a CruiseControl.NET server. Is it unsafe to use, or are there methods of securing it? For example, a super sandbox.

Comment: In the title. Is it unsafe to use, or are there methods of securing it? For example, a super sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can set up a master branch that you have commit access to and merge changes into that branch from others, so you can review code before commiting. Then give trusted members commit access to that branch to delegate code review before it reaches your testing branch.

You could probably (depending on the execution environment) also set up an execution jail to prevent rogue code from accessing restricted resources. Also, running tests as a restricted user helps.

So, my answer would be no, if you understand what's going on and can mitigate such risks.